# this program is incomplete but I'm supposed to ask the user for 10 2-digit numbers and then give the average

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, nasm

However I always get a segmentation fault I don't know what that means and how to approach it either
can someone please explain?

```
   segment .data
        ;welcome message
        welcomeMsg      db      "This NASM program calculates the average of 10 2-digit  numbers", 0xA
        msgLength       equ     $-welcomeMsg
        endingMsg       db      "The average is: ", 0xA
        endingLength    equ     $-endingMsg
        numbers         db      "enter 10 2-digit numbers",0xA
        numbersLength   equ     $-numbers

segment .bss
arrayOfNumber: resb 30 ;store the number entered by the user in arrayOfNumber   
arrayOfNumberLength equ $-arrayOfNumber
total :         resw 1 ; store the sum value of 10 numbers
segment .text

        global _start
_start:
        mov eax, 4      ;write()
        mov ebx, 1      ;where? output
        mov ecx, welcomeMsg ; what do we want to output
        mov edx, msgLength  ; the length of welcomeMsg
        int 0x80
        mov eax, 4
        mov ebx, 1
        mov ecx, numbers
        mov edx, numbersLength
        int 0x80
        ;Accept input and store it into arrayOfNumber
        sub esi, esi
        mov esi, 10
loop1:
        mov eax, 3      ;read 
        mov ebx, 0      ; from the standard input(keyboard/console)
        mov ecx, arrayOfNumber ; storing at memory location arrayOfNumber
        mov edx, 3      ;3 bytes
        int 0x80
        dec esi
        jnz loop1       ;if esi is not equal to zero goto loop1
        sub esi, esi
        sub edi,edi
        sub ecx, ecx
        sub ebx, ebx
loop2:
        sub eax, eax
        mov eax, [arrayOfNumber+edi]
        sub eax, 30
        add edi, 1
        imul eax, 10
        mov ebx, [arrayOfNumber+edi]
        sub ebx, 30
        add edi, 2
        add ebx, eax
        add ecx, ebx
        cmp edi, 30
  jne loop2

        sub edi, edi
        mov [total], ecx
        mov edi, 2
        mov ax, [total]
convert:
        mov bx, 10
        sub dx, dx
        div bx
        add dl, '0'
        mov [total + edi], dl
        dec edi
        cmp ax, 0
        jne convert
print:
        mov eax, 4
        mov ebx, 1
        mov ecx, total
        mov edx, 3
        int 0x80
        mov eax, 1
        mov ebx, 0 
        int 0x80
```

This is the whole program and the output of that I no longer have the segmentation fault but I do not get the right sum of these following numbers.

This NASM program calculates the average of 10 2-digit  numbers
enter 10 2-digit numbers
12
12
12
12
12
12
12
12
12
12
264
however I should actually have 120 as the sum of all of these integers not 264. If you could hep me please.

Comment: Can you post what is displayed before the segmentation fault?  BTW, a segmentation fault is a memory access violation.

Comment: I changed it,please take a look.

Comment: I don't know what happened the thing is showing it in a weird way

Comment: To make this readable, you should format the code as we have done.  Just select the code and click on the 'code' button.

Comment: Are you sure that you are converting to decimal?  Note what you are reading in via the keyboard vs. what number representation you are working with.

Comment: all right now it works.

Comment: yh I'm pretty sure I'm converting it to decimal.

Comment: I take the first character of my 2-digit number convert it to a number by subtracting 30 and then multiplying it by 10 since its 12 i have to multiply 1 by 10 and then add the next converted number

Comment: does that make sense? my mistake its i think when I am converting it back to a string

Comment: I should have said 'or vice versa'.  Good to see that it works!